# adding specific category query to an existing MySQL query in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am still only in the beginner stages of MySQL and am wondering how to add a specific category to this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(post_date, '%b') AS month , 
  MONTH(post_date) as numMonth, YEAR( post_date ) AS year, 
  COUNT( id ) as post_count 
FROM $wpdb->posts 
WHERE post_status = 'publish' and post_date <= now( ) and post_type = 'post' 
GROUP BY month , year ORDER BY post_date DESC
```

I found this code for getting the category `uncategorized`...

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts p 
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_term_relationships r ON r.object_id = p.ID     
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_terms t ON t.term_id = r.term_taxonomy_id 
WHERE p.post_status = 'publish' AND p.post_type = 'post' 
  AND t.slug = 'uncategorized'
```

I tried `UNION ALL` but that stops anything from appearing. Perhaps im gone a bit too far ahead of myself if Im trying to learn this stuff, as I cant even seem to get the second bit of the query working on its own.

Thanks

EDIT: In response to the first response ill add this code to explain a little further what Im doing, it is an archives widget that displays yearly then monthly. I have yet to find a simple way of doing this and have resorted to "better archives widget". This is the code they have included in their file that Im looking to change. If there was an easier way using `query_posts` Id be open to that.

```
global $wpdb;
    $prevYear = "";
    $currentYear = "";
    if ( $months = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(post_date, '%b') AS month , MONTH(post_date) as numMonth, YEAR( post_date ) AS year, COUNT( id ) as post_count FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' and post_date <= now( ) and post_type = 'post' GROUP BY month , year ORDER BY post_date DESC" ) ) {
    echo '<ul>';
        $count = 0;
        foreach ( $months as $month ) {

            $currentYear = $month->year;
            if ( ( $currentYear != $prevYear ) && ( $prevYear != "" ) ) { echo "</ul></li>"; }
            if ( $currentYear != $prevYear ) {  
             $count++ ?> 
            <li class="baw-year"><a href="<?php echo get_year_link( $month->year ); ?>"><?php echo $month->year; echo ' ('.$month->post_count . ')' ; ?> </a>
            <ul class="baw-months">
            <?php
            }   ?>
            <li class="baw-month"><a href="<?php echo get_month_link( $month->year, $month->numMonth ); ?>"><?php echo date('F', strtotime ($month->month)); ?><?php /*echo ' ' . $month->year;  */ ?></a></li>
            <?php
            $prevYear = $month->year;
        }//end foreach
    }
    ?>
    </ul></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're not using [query_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)?  (Parameters you can use in the query are [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters).)  Using the query_posts is a bit safer (and already built into WordPress) - with a custom query like this, you'll need to be sure you use $wpdb->prepare, etc. to make sure the query can't be injected.  but with the query_posts, you can add in the taxonomies, post types, post status, orderby, date/time, etc. and it writes the query for you and pulls what you need.

Comment: Hi Shelly, thanks for the reply, Ive updated the post above in response, to explain why Im not using `query_posts()`, ideally Id be using something like that I understand much better, but Im not sure if its possible without completely rewriting the entire thing. Basically all im looking to do is filter the query to a few specific categories.

Comment: Ahhh, I see.  When you start bringing categories into it, it gets tricky, since there's 3 tables that apply to this, and they need to be cross referenced.  The tables are wp_term_taxonomy (which contains the taxonomy - like "category" or "post_tag" - the term_taxonomy_id, and the term_id - which needs to match the term_id in wp_terms), wp_term_relationships (which contains term_taxonomy_id - which should match the term_relationships term_taxonomy_id - and the object_id, which would match your post_id), and wp_terms (contains term_id, name, and slug of the category you're searching for).

Comment: So you'd be looking for some sort of addition (this is rudimentary) like "WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id AND $wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->terms.term_taxonomy_id AND $wpdb->terms.slug = slug of whatever category you want".

Answer (score -1):

1. Try this code for displaying category posts -

   get_results( 
   "
   SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts
   LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON
   ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
   LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON
   ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
   WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
   AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
   AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = 3**(your category id)**
   ORDER BY post_date ASC
   "
   ); ?>
2. You can check "wp_terms" table for "term_taxonomy.term_id" ie. your
   category id.
3. Also, u can get your category-id by clicking edit button below
   particular category name in admin panel,you will see the id in the
   url.